# Does the integral of $\sin(x^2)$ between 0 and infinity converge

Tags: real-analysis

Does the integral of $\sin(x^2)$ between $0$ and infinity converge?

I am trying to use the sandwich theorem to prove this; I tried approximating the peaks to rectangles but that didn't really work, and I also tried the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: After change of variable to $u = x^2$, the integral converges by the improper integral version of [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). This is one of the easiest to use and yet very powerful test you should learn.

Comment: See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 3):

Change variables to $x=y^{1/2}$, then $dx=dy/(2y^{1/2})$ and you get
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{y}}{y^{1/2}} \, dy. $$
You can now split this up into intervals $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$, where the sine is alternately positive and negative. Since $y^{-1/2}$ is decreasing, you can then do the alternating series test to show it converges. (The possibility of trouble at $y=0$ is alleviated by $\sin{y} \sim y$ at $y=0$, so the integrand is $\sim y^{1/2}$, which is integrable.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it converges. You are asking about the Fresnel integral. It admits no closed form solution in terms of elementary functions. Wikipedia [1] has a good article on this integral, which includes a method of solution using contour integration which yields:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \sin(t^2)\mathrm{d}t = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}
$$

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral